# How to get css height property of an object and add 20px to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a custom nav bar with up/down scroll buttons.  These buttons should move the contents of an unordered list to show/hide items as expected.  I have this partially working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/96/

Though it currently only works with one item because I'm setting the position absolutely.  How can I grab the css 'top' property and just add 20px to whatever it was before?

code:

```
$('.down').click(function () {
    var $move = $('.side-study-box ul');
    $move.css({
        top: '-20px'
    })
})

$('.up').click(function () {
    var $move = $('.side-study-box ul');
    debugger;
    $move.css({
        top: '0'
    })
})
```

Comment: Try `$move.css({ top: '+=20' })` and `$move.css({ top: '-=20' })` - http://jsfiddle.net/kvfFv/

Comment: @Vega your fiddle isn't working for me in chrome, any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change `top: '-20px'` to `top: '-=20px'` it will increment down by 20px on each click. Instead of `top: '0'` in the second part, change it to `top: '+=20px'`.

Comment: And change the up function to '+=20px' instead of 0

Comment: Thanks - just tried that but it's not working for me in chrome :/ http://jsfiddle.net/kvfFv/1/

Comment: @RobVious You need to set `.side-study-box ul` to have a CSS property of `top: 0;` for it to work. Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/104/

Comment: So cool!  Thanks man.  I'd accept now but it won't let me because it's too early :p

Comment: @RobVious Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
var top = parseInt( $move.css('top') , 10) + 20;
$move.css('top', top+'px');
```